# System.Windows.Controls.Control without OnLoad method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, overriding

I need to modify some data bindings dynamically. So I had planned to perform the operation during/after the initialisation of the control in its parent.

But despite [the msdn page on Control.OnLoad Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), my class refuses to compile:

> Error  810 'Views.Test.OnLoad(System.EventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

My code:

```
class Test : Control 
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);            
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?

**Edit:** @Roken has noticed that I was mismatching with the System.Web.UI.Control  because my class derives from System.Windows.Controls.Control

So my question becomes: When and how should I perform my modifications on the binding of this control ? What method to override, or what event to subscribe to?

Comment: can you describe what are you trying to achieve? so we can advice you another way. btw you can handle the `Loaded` event.

Comment: I am subclassing my own converter for an enum displayed in a combo box. My converter object needs some external handling (like construction parameters) and is not a straigth forward converter, can't pass it simply in pure XAML, all the more so as the XAML file I have to work with is already 2000 lines (and this is evil). So I'd do this binding converter handling in the code behind my Control. The question is about how/when i can set the binding to the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a Windows Forms control or a Web control?  The link you provided is for the web control; the WinForms Control does not contain OnLoad().  OnCreateControl() might be of use to you for WinForms, or OnInitialized() for WPF.

Comment: a WPF control... what other method should I override or event to subscribe then ?

Comment: Look at OnInitialized() for WPF.

Comment: That's it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you derive from `System.Web.UI.Control` and not from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`?

`System.Windows.Forms.Control` does not provide a virtual `OnLoad` method.

Comment: indeed it is derived from System.Windows.Controls.Control... but in my case I don't know how to interact on the Control after it is initialised if there is not an entry point such as OnLoad override

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Controls.Control` doesn't provider `OnLoad` method, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control_methods.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I recommend you to create `ViewBinder` that will set up the converters with a little effort and with maximized transparency.

Check the Rob Eisenberg's speak at [MIX10](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/03/16/build-your-own-mvvm-framework-is-online.aspx) and Caliburn or the code from the speak that is downloadable from that page.

Based on conventions the framework locates UI element and matches it with property of the same name. And creates and tweaks the binding automatically:

```
private static void BindProperties(FrameworkElement view, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
  foreach (var property in properties)
  {
    var foundControl = view.FindName(property.Name) as DependencyObject;
    if(foundControl == null) // find the element
      continue;

    DependencyProperty boundProperty;
    if(!_boundProperties.TryGetValue(foundControl.GetType(), out boundProperty))
      continue;
    if(((FrameworkElement)foundControl).GetBindingExpression(boundProperty) != null) // already bound
      continue;

    var binding = new Binding(property.Name) // create the binding
    {
      Mode = property.CanWrite ? BindingMode.TwoWay : BindingMode.OneWay,
      ValidatesOnDataErrors = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, typeof(ValidationAttribute), true).Any()
    };

    if (boundProperty == UIElement.VisibilityProperty && typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
      binding.Converter = _booleanToVisibilityConverter;

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(foundControl, boundProperty, binding);
  }
}
```

Binding is done explicitly in `public static void Bind(object viewModel, DependencyObject view)` method, which takes all properties defined in `viewModel` type and binds them.